# php -- creating an object with an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to parse an XML file. I want to create a project object that has instances such as title,date,version and an array of files that hold all the files within the project. Everything seems to work such as the title,date,and version.

I checked by printing them out to see the results. However, when I try printing out the array to see if the contents are correct, nothing happens. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
<?php

require_once('project.php');
require_once('files.php');


function parse()
{
    $svn_list = simplexml_load_file("svn_list.xml");
    $dir = $svn_list->xpath("//entry[@kind = 'dir']");


    foreach ($dir as $node) {
        if (strpos($node->name, '/') == false) {

            $endProject = initProject($node);

        }
    }

    for ($x = 0; $x <= 7; $x++) {
        echo $endProject->fileListArray[$x]->name . "<br />\r\n";
    }

}

function initProject($node){

    $project = new project();
    $project->title = $node->name;
    $project->date = $node->commit->date;
    $project->version = $node->commit['revision'];

    initFiles($node,$project);

    return $project;

}

function initFiles($project){

    $svn_list = simplexml_load_file("svn_list.xml");
    $file = $svn_list->xpath("//entry[@kind ='file']/name[contains(., '$project->title')]/ancestor::node()[1]");
    //$file = $svn_list->xpath("//entry[@kind='file']/name[starts-with(., '$project->title')]/..");

    foreach($file as $fileObject){
        $files = new files();
        $files->size = $fileObject->size;
        $files->name = $fileObject->name;
        array_push($project->fileListArray, $files);
    }

}
```

`echo $endProject->fileListArray` prints out "Array" 7 times. However `echo $endProject->fileListArray[$x]->name` does not print anything out.

I'm not sure if the array is just not being initialized or if I'm parsing the XML file incorrectly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lists>
<list
        path="https://subversion....">
    <entry
            kind="file">
        <name>.project</name>
        <size>373</size>
        <commit
                revision="7052">
            <author></author>
            <date>2016-02-25T20:56:16.138801Z</date>
        </commit>
    </entry>
    <entry
            kind="file">
        <name>.pydevproject</name>
        <size>302</size>
        <commit
                revision="7052">
            <author></author>
            <date>2016-02-25T20:56:16.138801Z</date>
        </commit>
    </entry>
    <entry
            kind="dir">
        <name>Assignment2.0</name>
        <commit
                revision="7054">
            <author></author>
            <date>2016-02-25T20:59:11.144094Z</date>
        </commit>
    </entry>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function definition:

```
function initFiles( $project )
```

Your function call:

```
initFiles( $node, $project );
```

So, the function use `$node` as `$project`, but `$node` doesn't have `->fileListArray` property array, so your `array_push()` fails.

And, in the future, **don't forget to activate error checking** in our php code:

```
error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
```

With error checking, your original code output this error:

> PHP Warning:  array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in ...

Answer (score 0):

By default, function arguments are passed by value which means the value of the argument doesn't get changed outside of the function, unless you pass by reference. The [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) have more details but I think if you simply change:

`function initFiles($project){...` to `function initFiles(&$project){...` (note the **&**), it will work as you expect.

Comment: No. Objects are always passed for reference.